# the child and parent div have the same class name, how to select the parent div?

Tags: jquery, dom, children

HTML:

```
<div class="a" style="width:auto;....">  //I wanna add some inline-style to overwrite some stylesheet here.
  <div class="a">child</div>
  <div class="a">child</div>
</div>

<div class="a">
  <div class="a">child</div>
  <div class="a">child</div>
</div>
```

As you can see above , I wanna to grap the parent div's which has the same className with the child div,how can i do that?

Here is my code:

```
 var get_div_a = $('div.a');
 var len = get_div_a.size();
 var arr = [];

 for(var i = 0; i < len ; i++){

  if($(get_div_a[i]).children('div.a')!==0){
     ...no idea ???
  }

}
```

Comment: Is the nesting only ever one level (i.e. as you've demonstrated)?

Comment: you probably already thought of this, but can you add another class for the parent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're just after filtering the nodes that have child nodes, you could do this:

```
$('div.a > div.a').parent()
```

The first expression gets all child nodes; after applying `.parent()` it returns the set of parent nodes (they're already filtered, i.e. no duplicates).

Answer (score 0):

```
 var get_div_a = $('div.a');
 var len = get_div_a.size();
 var arr = [];

 for(var i = 0; i < len ; i++){

 if($(get_div_a[i]).children('div.a')!==0){
    $(this) //this is needed div
  }

 }
```